# Simulation of a large network by GNS3

Tags: gns3

I want to simulate a large network of 40 routers with GNS3 or OPNET or VIRL or …

In the real network, routers route their incoming traffic (coming from an external network) and deliver it to an another external network. Total network traffic is up to 100Gbps (But I do not need to receive 100 Gbps traffic in the simulation!). The link between routers is a few kilometers of fiber optics.

Suppose there is no problem in buying servers and hardware.

GNS3 guide states that "GNS3 will provide around 1,000 packets per second throughput in a virtual environment"

Can I simulate such a network with GNS3 or OPNET or VIRL or …?

What is the maximum traffic that these emulators can support (using powerful hardware) on such a network?

What factors limit it? GNS3 or interfaces between VMs or Cisco images or routers or ...?

Thanks.

*** Edit ***

Suppose I want to run a GNS3 simulator and 25 vSRX routers on one system.

According to the information in [Sizing your computer for GNS3](https://adosztal.blogspot.com/2018/01/sizing-your-computer-for-network-labs.html), I need a server with 100 GB of RAM and 17 cores. I have a server with 128 GB of RAM and 32 cores.

Given that all routers and GNS3 are running on the same system, the speed of data exchange between them can be tens of gigabytes. is that true?

Is it really possible to exchange such traffic between routers with such hardware?
If not, what is the maximum traffic? What limits it?
If I run each router on a separate hardware and they are connected via cable, will the speed increase?

Is it possible to simulate such a network with another simulator such as OPNET or ...?

Comment: GNS3 is by no means a tool to simulate network performance or emulate long distance links. It's used to model topologies and test configurations.

Comment: Is it possible to simulate such a network with another simulator such as OPNET or ...?

Comment: I'll spell it out one more time: emulators are not used for performance testing. They're in no way capable of doing anywhere near the performance of real hardware, since all instructions are emulated and no hardware ASICs for performance optimization are available.

Comment: Ok! What is the maximum traffic with these emulators? What limits it?

Comment: How can vSRX support 100Gbps?

Comment: vSRX is not GNS3 or any other simulator. It's a virtual machine which you need to run on a hypervisor, which requires very specific hardware settings to achieve high throughput, like PCI passthrough. You wouldn't be able to run a large number of those on a single machine, because you'd run out of interfaces, cores and memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
Can I run multiple vSRXs on a number of VMs (with specific hardware settings) to simulate such a network and to achieve high throughput?

Comment: I already answered that in my previous comment. I'm getting tired of repeating myself by now.

Comment: Ok! What is the maximum traffic with these emulators? What limits it?

Comment: The fact that they EMULATE. Really, you're using the wrong tool for the job and we're running around in circles here. I can think of a number of things which will be a limit, but since I don't attempt to do such things (since they DO NOT MAKE SENSE) I don't know. Possible bottlenecks: your CPU, your inability to generate enough traffic in an emulator, the scheduler on your host, memory, the lack of hardware acceleration, inefficient programming of the emulator, etc. As I have said a number of times now: you're looking at the wrong tool for the job.Performance testing on emulators is pointless.

Comment: What you want is real network equipment and some specialized tools that will inject the delay of distance. Such equipment exists. Either you build or rent such a lab, but what you want to do is not what the emulators do.

Comment: I think I have a misconception about GNS3. Suppose GNS3 is running on one PC and two vSRX routers are running on two separate PCs. PCs are connected with Ethernet cable. The routers are also connected within GNS3. Is the traffic between the two routers exchanged via the PC running GNS3 or directly via the network cable between the two routers?

Answer (score 1):

While you can very well simulate the general functions and workings of a network in GNS3 (or any other decent simulator), it's not well suited for performance evaluation.

GNS3 runs on normal host CPUs with considerable processing overhead, coming nowhere close to the wire-speed hardware processing that is pretty much standard today, especially in terms of latency.

If the datasheet specs and the vendor reputation aren't enough and you really need actual evaluation you should consider arranging a lab trial period with the vendor.

Comment: That won't work. I think people explained it a number of times now: these tools are not meant for performance testing. They're meant to simulate topologies. You don't do performance tests on emulators. As @Zac67 said, if you need to do performance tests, build a physical lab.

Comment: Suppose I want to run a GNS3 simulator and 25 vSRX routers on one system. 

I need a server with 100 GB of RAM and 17 cores. I have a server with 128 GB of RAM and 32 cores. 

Given that all routers and GNS3 are running on the same system, the speed of data exchange between them can be tens of gigabytes. is that true?

Is it really possible to exchange such traffic between routers with such hardware?

Comment: If not, what is the maximum traffic? What limits it?
If I run each router on a separate hardware and they are connected via cable, will the speed increase?

Comment: Is it possible to simulate such a network with another simulator such as OPNET or ...?

Comment: You do not do performance testing on emulators. I don't see in how many more ways we need to answer this question.

Comment: @AliUt Your simulation question boils down to what (performance) a host can or can't do - that is beyond the scope of this site and off-topic here, actually.